# Summing this series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2n-1}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I wish to sum the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{2n-1}{2^n}$.

I notice that by writing $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n-1)\dfrac{1}{2^n}$, $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ is a geometric series and can be summed easily. But the next step I think I did wrong is

$$2n-1\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{2^n}$$

I don't think I can pull out $2n-1$ like a constant because that will affect the sum. What should I have done. The series converges to $3$ according Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: You could show that the sequence converges, and then distribute accordingly

Comment: @EveeTrainer The problem asks to find the sum of this series, so it is a convergent series. Sure I can test it but I thought you don't need to. What do you mean by distributing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to solve this question without calculus--

As you have mentioned, $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is indeed a geometric series.

We know that $2n-1$ is an arithmatic series.

Proof--   $2n-1-(2(n-1)-1)=2$, which is a constant. hence we get first term $t_1=1$ and common difference $d=2$

As we have A.P. in the numerator and G.P in the denominator (r<1), it is an infinite convergent [Arithmetic-(o)-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence), [A.G.P](https://brilliant.org/wiki/arithmetic-geometric-progression/), which (according to the question) converges.

The formula for sum of  infinite AGP  where r is less than unity ($r=\frac{1}{2}$)--
$t_0+(t_1)r+(t_2)r^2+...$ is

$S_{\infty}=\frac{t_0}{1-r}+\frac{\left(r\cdot d\right)}{\left(1-r\right)^2}$

but as we do not want $t_0$ in our required sum, can calculate $t_0=-1$, calculate the entire sum using the formula and add 1 to get the desired answer as 3

Comment: PS--by without calculus i mean that this can be solved by high school maths, even unaware of the calculus and limit-theory  lying underneath it....

Comment: of course if you shove this formula down their throat, they are going to be able to plug in the values, but what is the point? Better explain patiently and show them how to do it.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n-1}{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{2^n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}.
$$
The second sum is geometric and converges to $1$. We just need to deal with the first. To do this, use the relation
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}
$$
valid for $\lvert z\rvert <1$ and differentiate to get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1}=\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}.
$$
Next, evaluate at $z=\frac{1}{2}$ to get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{2^n}=\frac{1}{(1/2)^2}=4.
$$
So, the result is $3$.

Comment: The probabilist in me would be amiss without pointing out that $\sum\frac{n}{2^n}$ is the expected number of times to flip a fair coin until you get heads. You can show this is equal to $2$ (which agrees with intuition) without any sums.

Comment: That's a nice interpretation and probably a much nicer answer than mine. You could write it up!

Comment: @AlekosRobotis  agree with you.  This interpretation deserves more attention

Comment: I got it, thank you, shouldn't reply in haste.

Comment: Yeah, such a nice interpretation. I couldn't imagine how series can be used in probability. Make me think of Laplace and his Theorie analytique de probabilite

Comment: Don't understand why $z=\dfrac{1}{2}$. This video didn't explain. This method may be known among other students. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ch9uCBm-kUE

Comment: It is _evaluated_ at $z=\frac{1}{2}$ because it helps us solve the problem.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis suppose we don't do the other half (in the video), how do you know $z=\dfrac{1}{2}$? There must be a justification for this little but important step.

Answer (score 3):

Write $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {2n-1}{2^n} = \frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2n-1)\left(\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\right)^{2n-2}$$

Notice that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-1)x^{2n-2} = \frac d{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2n-1} = \frac d{dx}\left(\frac {x}{1-x^2}\right) = \frac {1+x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}$$ for $|x|<1$. Hence:

$$\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2n-1)\left(\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\right)^{2n-2} = \frac12\left(\frac {1+1/2}{(1-1/2)^2}\right) = 3$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another approach, again with no calculus involved

Firstly we split the sum, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n-1}{2^n}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}$

as noticed, the rightmost term is GP and convergent to 1, what now remains is the fist term.

We expand the sum as--

$\frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{5}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+\frac{7}{128}+............\infty$

split the odd terms

$\frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{\left(2+1\right)}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{\left(4+1\right)}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+\frac{\left(6+1\right)}{128}+............\infty$

$=\frac{(1)}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{\left(2\right)}{8}+\frac{\left(1\right)}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{\left(4\right)}{32}+\frac{\left(1\right)}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+\frac{\left(6\right)}{128}+\frac{\left(1\right)}{128}+............\infty$

Take out the terms with 1
$=\left(\frac{\left(1\right)}{2}+\frac{\left(1\right)}{8}+\frac{\left(1\right)}{32}+\frac{\left(1\right)}{128}+.......\infty \right)+\left(\frac{2}{4}+\frac{\left(2\right)}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{\left(4\right)}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+\frac{\left(6\right)}{128}+............\infty \right)$

But we know that the sum $\left(\frac{\left(1\right)}{2}+\frac{\left(1\right)}{8}+\frac{\left(1\right)}{32}+\frac{\left(1\right)}{128}+.......\infty \right)$ is GP and converges to $\frac{2}{3}$

> $\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{2}{3}$

Hence, we get
$\frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{2}{3}+\left(\frac{2}{4}+\frac{\left(2\right)}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{\left(4\right)}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+\frac{\left(6\right)}{128}+............\infty \right)$

Simplifying the right terms, we get

$\frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{2}{3}+3\left(\frac{\left(2\right)}{8}+\frac{\left(4\right)}{32}+\frac{\left(6\right)}{128}+............\infty \right)$  -------(1)

Now we begin from the expansion, this time splitting the odd terms with minus one--

$\frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{5}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+............\infty $

$\frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{\left(2-1\right)}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{\left(4-1\right)}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{\left(6-1\right)}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+............\infty $

$\frac{n}{2^n}=\frac{\left(2\right)}{2}-\frac{\left(1\right)}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{\left(4\right)}{8}-\frac{\left(1\right)}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{\left(6\right)}{32}-\frac{{\left(1\right)}}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+............\infty $

$\frac{n}{2^n}=\left(\frac{\left(2\right)}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{\left(4\right)}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{\left(6\right)}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+............\infty \right)-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{32}+........\infty \right)$

$\frac{n}{2^n}=\left(\frac{\left(2\right)}{2}+\frac{2}{4}+\frac{\left(4\right)}{8}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{\left(6\right)}{32}+\frac{6}{64}+............\infty \right)-\frac{2}{3}$

$\frac{n}{2^n}=3\left(\frac{2}{4}+\frac{4}{16}+\frac{6}{64}+............\infty \right)-\frac{2}{3}$

Multiply and divide by 2

$\frac{n}{2^n}=6\left(\frac{2}{8}+\frac{4}{32}+\frac{6}{128}+............\infty \right)-\frac{2}{3}$  --------(2)

Solve 1 & 2 equations simultaneously, and we get $\frac{n}{2^n}=2$

Final answer

> $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{2n-1}{2^n}=2\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{n}{2^n}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^n}$
> =$2\cdot \left(2\right)-1=3$

P.S-- We can perform these operations ONLY as we know that the sum converges...Incredibly sorry if  I may have missed some finer higher-level details of why we can perform these operations for these infinite sums....

Comment: That's okay man, just relive the 18th century, when we were all innocent and waltz to heaven with infinite series. :)